# Show 0 value if data has null value in data studio

Tags: looker-studio

i have a data like this:

```
date          total       status
2020-01-01    100         NOT OK
2020-01-02    100         OK
2020-01-03    200         NOT OK
2020-01-04    300         OK
```

I am using data studio line chart to show `total` value that has `OK` status based on the date with expected result like this:

```
date          total       
2020-01-01     0        
2020-01-02    100        
2020-01-03     0         
2020-01-04    300
```

i have been implement the data in data studio line chart but only show the date has value with OK status like this:

```
date          total       
2020-01-02    100        
2020-01-04    300
```

how the way to show the `date` and `total` value if any data has no value like i write before ? how to handle it ?

Comment: Have you tried using an `IF` or `CASE` statement in your `SELECT` query?

Comment: add query also...

Answer (score 3):

Created a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/06aa33d9-6ca7-44aa-9963-1f0568c7edc9) to demonstrate as well as a GIF to elaborate on the process below:

**1) Chart**

- [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697)

**2) Dimension**

- `date`

**3) Metric**

- Create a [calculated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685):

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(status, "OK") THEN total
  ELSE NULL
END
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `CASE` statement to get the required result:

```
SELECT date,(CASE WHEN status="OK' THEN Total END) AS TotalA
FROM table
ORDER BY date;
```